# How can I sum the results of two queries based on the Group BY column?

Tags: mysql

I have a matches table with all history games played in a football (soccer) division. It goes around 30000 games and my challenge is to retrieve the Wins, Draw and Loses for a given team vs the rest.

For my question I'll just use the draws, in order to retrieve my draws I have 2 possible scenarios:

1. The team is the home team
2. The team is the away team

So and according to my data the query for the first scenario where my team is the home team is like this:

```
SELECT 
    matches.away_team as VS, 
    COUNT(matches.idmatch) AS TIES 
FROM
    my_football_database.matches 
WHERE 
    home_team = 14 
    AND home_team_goals = away_team_goals 
    AND aet = "N" AND PK = "N" 
GROUP BY 
    away_team 
LIMIT 5;
```

Output:

```
+------+------+
| VS   | TIES |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    3 |    3 |
|    4 |    2 |
|    8 |    1 |
|    9 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

The second scenario is when my team is the away team, so it goes like this:

```
SELECT 
    matches.home_team as VS, 
    COUNT(matches.idmatch) AS TIES 
FROM
    my_football_database.matches 
WHERE 
    away_team = 14 
    AND home_team_goals = away_team_goals 
    AND aet = "N" AND PK = "N" 
GROUP BY 
    home_team 
LIMIT 5;
```

Output:

```
+------+------+
| VS   | TIES |
+------+------+
|    2 |    4 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    7 |    1 |
|    8 |    3 |
|    9 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

As you can see as an example:

- when my team (ID=14) was playing as the home team vs team ID=3, a total of 3 matches ended as a tie
- In the second result, when my team (ID=14) was playing as the away team vs team ID=3, a total of 2 matches ended as a tie

How can I sum the result of TIES, based on the "VS" Ids? Like, after listing all Ties for a team playing as home team, grouped by the away team and listing all Ties for a team playing as away team, grouped by the home team, Join both columns, based on the "Vs" ID.

The example result in this case would be:

```
+------+------+
| VS   | TIES |
+------+------+
|    2 |    5 |
|    3 |    5 |
|    4 |    2 |
|    7 |    1 |
|    8 |    4 |
|    9 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

**NOTE:** I have to get to the point that a single query, can give me a table with all Wins, Loses and Draws for a given team, grouped by the team they played against.

That is 14 total scenarios. Home and Away Draws (2), Home and Away wins regular, awarded and in penalties (6). Home and Away loses regular, awarded and in penalties (6).

Therefore, I'm not looking for a piece of code that may solve the Draws deal but more like a HINT on what to study, research or implement for this problem. My first Idea would be to create each scenario separately, and then use them as subqueries but I've been told that is not convenient for performance.

Comment: I can't understand your description. Can you show a sample of the desired results?

Comment: I just added one and tried to explain better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` constructs:

```
select 
  otherteam,
  count(case when mygoals > othergoals then 1 end) as won,
  count(case when mygoals = othergoals then 1 end) as ties,
  count(case when mygoals < othergoals then 1 end) as lost
from
(
  select
    11 as myteam,
    case when home_team = 11 then away_team else home_team end as otherteam,
    case when home_team = 11 then home_team_goals else away_team_goals end as mygoals,
    case when home_team = 11 then away_team_goals else home_team_goals end as othergoals
  from mydb.matches
  where (home_team = 11 or away_team = 11)
) whoiswho
group by otherteam;
```

(Oops, sorry, I guess that's slightly more than "like a HINT".)

Comment: This kinda solved everything, genius. Although I will sit down and study thee case constructs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` of the two queries, and then sum the rows with the same `VS` column.

```
SELECT VS, SUM(TIES) AS TIES
FROM (
    (SELECT matches.away_team as VS, count(matches.idmatch) as TIES 
    from my_football_database.matches WHERE home_team = 14 
    AND home_team_goals = away_team_goals 
    AND aet = "N" AND PK = "N" 
    GROUP BY away_team 
    LIMIT 5)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT matches.home_team as VS, count(matches.idmatch) as TIES 
    from my_football_database.matches WHERE away_team = 14 
    AND home_team_goals = away_team_goals 
    AND aet = "N" AND PK = "N" 
    GROUP BY home_team 
    LIMIT 5)) AS u
GROUP BY VS
```